# Logs not displaying for appcelerator android app

Tags: android, appcelerator

I was using `monitor.bat` for getting Appcelerator mobile application logs. Recently even if the phone is detecting, logs not displaying. Please advise.

Comment: invalidate and restart the android studio

Comment: im not using android studio. I have installed android sdk for appcelerator. Please advise what could be done?

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator logs on android are terminated if you either kill app, cable disconnected or app crashes. You can try the following:

1. Re run the app in Appcelerator Studio.
2. Use adb logcat command to get logs in termianl using this command:
   /path/to/adb logcat TiAPI:I *:S
3. Check the logs in Android studio logcat view.